# Password strength meter with Semantic UI

Tags: passwords, progress, semantic-ui

Please advice how to implement password strength meter with Semantic UI progress bar?

```
<div class="ui left icon input">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="">
<i class="icon-lock teal icon"></i>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached progress">
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tutsplus has an awesome tutorial to calculate password strength using JavaScript which you can find [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-simple-password-strength-checker--net-7565).

The tutorial will give you a score out of 100. Use this score to populate the progress bar in Semantic UI like this:

```
$('.progress').progress({
    percent: score
});
```